# iPhone 4.0 Beta compile for 3.1.3

Tags: iphone, sdk, compilation, beta

I downloaded the iPhone 4.0 Beta. But for my projects I need to compile for 3.1.3 to be able to still submit my projects to the App Store. If I run an old project that isn't a problem I can see all the versions, but when I start a new project I can only pick the 4.0 beta, how can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Open your project. In XCode open the project settings (Project -> Edit Project Settings). Choose the build tab, and pick an appropriate Base SDK from the options under the architecture group.

Answer (score 1):

You should not submit apps with beta versions of the SDK. Rather install beta SDKs alongside one for production builds.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by that and how I could accomplish such a thing. Would you mind explaining?

Comment: @Mark: Beta releases of SDKs typically cannot be used for submitting applications to the App Store until they mature to a specific level.  Even then, Apple strongly recommends against this.  To install the beta SDK at a different location on your system, go through the normal install process until you hit the screen shown here: http://emberapp.com/users/jurewitz/images/installer and select a different install location than /Developer there.  You will, of course, need to reinstall the stable SDK at the old /Developer location.